# Returning IAsyncEnumerable<T> and NotFound from Asp.Net Core Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the right signature for a controller action that returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` and a `NotFoundResult` but is still processed in an async fashion?

I used this signature and it doesn't compile because `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` isn't awaitable:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(await repository.GetAll(id)); // GetAll() returns an IAsyncEnumerable
    }
    catch (NotFoundException e)
    {
        return NotFound(e.Message);
    }
}
```

This one compiles fine but its signature isn't async. So I'm worried whether it'll block thread pool threads or not:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(repository.GetAll(id)); // GetAll() returns an IAsyncEnumerable
    }
    catch (NotFoundException e)
    {
        return NotFound(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I tried using a `await foreach` loop on like this but that obviously wouldn't compile either:

```
[HttpGet]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<MyObject> GetAll(Guid id)
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<MyObject> objects;
    try
    {
        objects = repository.GetAll(id); // GetAll() returns an IAsyncEnumerable
    }
    catch (NotFoundException e)
    {
        return NotFound(e.Message);
    }

    await foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        yield return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're returning multiple `MyObject` items with the same `id`? Normally You wouldn't send a `NotFound` for something that returns an `IEnumerable` - it would just be empty - or you would return the single item with the requested `id`/`NotFound`.

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` is awaitable. Use `await foreach(var item from ThatMethodAsync()){...}`.

Comment: If you want to return `IAsyncEnumerable<MyObject>`, just return the result, eg `return objects`. That *won't* convert an HTTP action to a streaming gRPC or SignalR method though. The middleware will still consume the data and send a single HTTP response to the client

Comment: Option 2 is fine. The ASP.NET Core plumbing takes care of the enumeration and is `IAsyncEnumerable`-aware as of 3.0.

Comment: Thanks guys. I know I don' t have return a 404 here, but this is just a contrived example. The actual code is quite different. @KirkLarkin sorry to be a pest, but are you 100%  sure this won't cause any blocking? If yes, then Option 2 is the obvious solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Option 2, which passes an implementation of `IAsyncEnumerable<>` into the `Ok` call, is fine. The ASP.NET Core plumbing takes care of the enumeration and is `IAsyncEnumerable<>`-aware as of 3.0.

Here's the call from the question, repeated for context:

> ```
> return Ok(repository.GetAll(id)); // GetAll() returns an IAsyncEnumerable
> ```

The call to [`Ok`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Ok_System_Object_) creates an instance of [`OkObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which inherits [`ObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The value passed in to `Ok` is of type `object`, which is held in the `ObjectResult`'s [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult.value?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ObjectResult_Value) property. ASP.NET Core MVC uses the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), whereby the command is an implementation of `IActionResult` and is executed using an implementation of [`IActionResultExecutor<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactionresultexecutor-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

For `ObjectResult`, [`ObjectResultExecutor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.objectresultexecutor?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is used to turn the `ObjectResult` into a HTTP response. It's the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs#L119-L126) of `ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync` that is `IAsyncEnumerable<>`-aware:

> ```
> public virtual Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
> {
>     // ...
>
>     var value = result.Value;
>
>     if (value != null && _asyncEnumerableReaderFactory.TryGetReader(value.GetType(), out var reader))
>     {
>         return ExecuteAsyncEnumerable(context, result, value, reader);
>     }
>
>     return ExecuteAsyncCore(context, result, objectType, value);
> }
> ```

As the code shows, the `Value` property is checked to see if it implements `IAsyncEnumerable<>` (the details are hidden in the call to [`TryGetReader`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/AsyncEnumerableReader.cs#L53)). If it does, [`ExecuteAsyncEnumerable`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ObjectResultExecutor.cs#L129) is called, which performs the enumeration and then passes the enumerated result into `ExecuteAsyncCore`:

> ```
> private async Task ExecuteAsyncEnumerable(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, object asyncEnumerable, Func<object, Task<ICollection>> reader)
> {
>     Log.BufferingAsyncEnumerable(Logger, asyncEnumerable);
>
>     var enumerated = await reader(asyncEnumerable);
>     await ExecuteAsyncCore(context, result, enumerated.GetType(), enumerated);
> }
> ```

`reader` in the above snippet is where the enumeration occurs. It's buried a little, but you can see the source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/AsyncEnumerableReader.cs#L80-L99):

> ```
> private async Task<ICollection> ReadInternal<T>(object value)
> {
>     var asyncEnumerable = (IAsyncEnumerable<T>)value;
>     var result = new List<T>();
>     var count = 0;
>
>     await foreach (var item in asyncEnumerable)
>     {
>         if (count++ >= _mvcOptions.MaxIAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit)
>         {
>             throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.FormatObjectResultExecutor_MaxEnumerationExceeded(
>                 nameof(AsyncEnumerableReader),
>                 value.GetType()));
>         }
>
>         result.Add(item);
>     }
>
>     return result;
> }
> ```

The `IAsyncEnumerable<>` is enumerated into a `List<>` using `await foreach`, which, almost by definition, doesn't block a request thread. As Panagiotis Kanavos called out in a comment on the OP, this enumeration is performed in full *before* a response is sent back to the client.